# Autocomplete host names in Windows CMD

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, autocomplete, hosts-file, hostname

[WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) Bash thing does it, for example, when using `ping` :

[image]

But [CMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe) can not do it.
Is there a way to achieve that?

**Note:** I know about [clink](https://github.com/mridgers/clink), but it does not provide *hosts file* auto-completion, which is what I am looking for. I am not interested here in PowerShell. I suspect that *extending clink* could be a solution.

Comment: bash can autocomplete a lot of things, because applications can tell the `complete` command information about its command line parameters and other things. Powershell can also autocomplete arguments but I'm not sure about its capability

Comment: This does work for me.  Windows 10 Pro -10.0.17763 Build 17763. E.g.  I have a file called `test` in `C:\temp\`.  If I `CD` to `C:\temp` I can type `ping`, hit tab and it auto-completes it to `ping test`.  Also works with directories.

Comment: WSL Bash is Linux; Command Prompt is Windows; There are tons of things one can do and the other can’t.  Try using PowerShell instead

Comment: @HelpingHand, that is nonsense, it is simply auto-completing that file. I look for `hosts` autocompletion. @Ramhound, that is the point, find a way where CMD can do the good things Linux bash already does.

Comment: @nephewtom Then i don't understand what you're asking as your question isn't clear.  I thought you had a directory of files/folders which are host names.  For speed you wanted to tab complete these as a parameter to ping. This sounds more ping specific than OS specific.

Comment: Well, `WSL Bash` does that for any *host* related command. It could be ping, ssh, scp, etc. I clarified a little more the question.

Comment: cmd has no interface for that purpose. PowerShell is much more powerful and can do anything bash can. [It is possible to make autocompletion in Powershell work like in bash?](https://superuser.com/q/206590/241386), [Custom PowerShell tab-completion for a specific command?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33497205/995714), [Adding tab-completion to your PowerShell Functions](https://foxdeploy.com/2017/01/13/adding-tab-completion-to-your-powershell-functions/)

Comment: @phuclv, I a complete ignorant about PowerShell. That is the reason I explicitly stated CMD in the question and marked it with `cmd.exe` tag. If I wanted to do it with PowerShell, I would have looked for that. I think this can be achieved with clink.

Comment: messing with cmd on this doesn't worth the time. It doesn't even support **command autocomplete** while powershell have that and argument autocomplete by default. It also doesn't have proper color output support

Comment: As I told you, `clink` solves the autocompletion. And `ConEmu` solves the colors with https://conemu.github.io/en/CmdPrompt.html . So there are ways to do it. I do not need to mess with PowerShell.

Answer (score -2):

Not directly using ping command.

Ping only sends ICMP packets to single IP address, install nmap and you can do that from CMD though you need to read the manual for the commands

Comment: I don't get what you are saying... What does nmap or ping have to do with CMD autocompletion capabilities? It is not related.